# Should I always level up a gem ASAP?

Tags: path-of-exile

The UI will tell me to left click the + button to level up a gem, but it also tells me to right click on it and I can dismiss the leveling up process.

Should I always level up the skill gems or is there ever a reason not to?

Comment: I recall not wanting to level a gem so that I could share it with my other characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skill gems have requirements, and those requirements increase with the level of the gem.

If the requirements are not met, the gem will not be active. To prevent accidentally doing so, the game does not allow you to level a gem if the new requirements are not met.

**If you expect that you will not be able to meet the requirements in the near future** - e.g. because you are about to replace a ring which has a minor bonus to a stat required by the gem - **it might be better not to level the gem**.

This usually only happens for gems that require a stat that is not your main stat.

---

A second reason not to level a gem, is more specific. There are a few skill gems that put limits on their linked gem. E.g. [Cast when Damage Taken](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Cast_when_Damage_Taken_Support) (values between brackets depend on the level of the gem).

> Casts Supported Spells when you take a total of (528-3272) Damage
>
> (-70-6)% more Damage
>
> **This Gem can only Support Skill Gems requiring Level (38-70) or lower**
>
> You cannot Cast Supported Spells directly

You should not level the linked gem beyond the limit put upon it by this gem.

Because the required damage will increase with the level, some people even advice not to level the Cast when Damage Taken gem past a certain point. This, of course, depends on the linked skill and personal preference, and is very situational.

Comment: Gem Level can be lowered again with orbs of regret and orbs of scouring, should the need arise.